# Why can't PyCharm autocomplete turtle.mainloop() function? How to know which function from module is available to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, turtle-graphics

It's possible to call `turtle.mainloop()` or `turtle.exitonclick()` without creating instance of `Turtle` or `Screen` class.

But PyCharm seems to have trouble auto-completing these functions after pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>.

Noticed `turtle` module has function called `_make_global_funcs` which I think makes class methods callable using `<module_name>.<function_name>` syntax.

How to know which methods are available for direct use and which ones not? If I can directly call `turtle.exitonclick()`, then I don't have to create instance of `Screen` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `turtle.py` module is unusual.  To make it easier for beginning programmers to use, I assume, all methods of the Turtle class are also available as top level functions that operate on the default (unnamed) turtle instance. All methods of the Screen class are also available as top level functions that operate on the default (sole) screen instance.

This doesn't help you know which methods PyCharm can/will autocomplete but when you call `turtle.Screen()`, you aren't creating an instance of the `Screen` class, you're just getting a pointer to the existing instance.

Because of its unusual design, I feel that `turtle.py` is one module that can violate the no `import *` rule since it's aimed at beginners.  Doing this may help PyCharm distinguish between functions and methods and do the right thing. Or not.